# DataGrid cells - convert decimal and binary numbers to hexa

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

In my WPF application I have a DataTable populating a DataGrid, and there is the ability to edit cells in the DataGrid.
I want, that in specific columns, if the user enters a decimal or binary number, it will change automatically to a hexadecimal number.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use CellEditEnding event or implement a notifyPropertychanged

Comment: If you are using WPF use MvvM pattern, as for the DataGrid I've not worked with it, but I found this [wpfTutorial.net](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html). HTH

Comment: Yes, but how do i refer to the specific cell? like this.convertToHexa or something @moez

Comment: The DataGrid supports editing of its cells by the user. When the edit is finished by the user, the CellEditEnding event is triggered. And in this C# method, we can cancel the edit. This is useful if we detect an invalid entry.If you need i can give you an example how to get data and valid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your specified requirements. The method described in the comments was to handle the [`DataGrid.CellEditEnding` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding" />
```

From the linked page, this event:

> Occurs before a cell edit is committed or canceled.

So, after a user has finished typing a value in any cell, this event will be raised. Therefore, all you need to do now is to call a conversion method from this event handler:

```
private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text = 
        ConvertToHexadecimal(((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text);
}

private string ConvertToHexadecimal(string input)
{
    int number = 0;
    bool isInputInteger = int.TryParse(input, out number); 
    return isInputInteger ? number.ToString("X") : input; 
}
```